# A question about noetherian modules and their homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

This question is from notes of algebraic geometry from which I am self studying and I need help with it.

> Question (a) Let A be a commutative ring and M be a noetherian A-module. Prove that A/ Ann(M) is a noetherian ring.

Work: M is noetherian means that every ascending chain of subsets of A will terminate and also that M is a finitely generated A-module.  Ann(M) = { $x\in A|$ x.m =0 for all $m\in M$ }But I am not able to get any intuition on how to prove that A/Ann(M) is noetherian.

> (b) If A is noetherian, then prove that any surjective hom $\phi:A\to A$ is an isomorphism.

Work: I have to prove that $\phi(a) =0 $ implies that a=0 , given A is surjective. But how should I proceed? Can you please give a hint?

Comment: These are two separate questions and should be asked in separate posts. The second question is already answered on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145310/proving-that-surjective-endomorphisms-of-noetherian-modules-are-isomorphisms-and).

Comment: @KReiser In notes they are asked in same question in two parts (a) and (b) that's why I asked this way.

Comment: It turns out that both of your questions have been addressed here on MSE before, therefore I've marked your post as a duplicate of the relevant questions.

Comment: @KReiser Got it!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355919/quotient-of-annihilator-module